# How autofilter column with specific text and numeric values?

Tags: excel, vba, text, numeric, autofilter

I have this range, say, A1:H2000, that needs to be filtered in column A - i have two different critera for this filter as following:

criteria 1 - array("C1","C2", "C3")

criteria 2 - numeric value is greater than 0

```
With activesheet
    .range("A1:H2000").autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("C1","C2","C3"), operator:=xlFilterValues
    .range("A1:H2000").autofilter Field:=1, Criteria2:=">0", operator:=xlOr
End with
```

When i re-prioritise the two lines - the filter only ends up fulfiling one criteria only  and never both that is what i need.

Appreciate any advice in advance.

Comment: Looks strange to me. How can a cell contain a string (C1 or C2 or C3) and a numeric value (>0) in the same moment?

Comment: Did you mean `xlOr` instead of `xlAnd`?

Comment: Column A contains values such as  C1,1,2,3,(empty),(empty),C2,1,2,3,4,(empty),C3,1,2,(empty),(empty),(empty).
I have tried with xlor, and xlAnd - it does not filter the rows with value matching either one of these criteria.

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually?

Comment: What data should be filtered out (besides empty cells)?

Comment: You cannot simultaneously apply both criteria. If you really want it, each cell needs to be individually validated against the criteria using VBA, and then the undesired rows can be hidden accordingly. What's next step processing after filtering? Maybe there is a walkaround solution.